# Inserting data into the mysql database from perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL database:

```
$response = $client->fql->query(
  query => '
    SELECT name, email, birthday, username, first_name, last_name, pic
    FROM   user
    WHERE  uid =  me()
  ',
);

print join "\n Name:",  sort map { $_->{name} } @$response;

$dbh->do("
  INSERT INTO Users(SNo,Name,Email,Birthday,UserName,FirstName,LastName)
  VALUES(1,
         sort map { $_->{name} } @$response,
         'imm\@gmail.com',
         '1987/12/10',
         'imm',
         'imm',
         'Dee')
");

$dbh->disconnect();
```

used the mysql query in one line.

This above print statement is printing the name correctly but why the above sql insert statement is not working?

I connect the db and after that i am receiving the value and printing in the browser is working.

Why does the mysql statement not accept the value?
When inserting the database is not working?

Comment: You could do this in a single `INSERT ... SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [the official doc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql.pm)

and specially this :

```
# INSERT some data into 'foo'. We are using $dbh->quote() for
# quoting the name.
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, " . $dbh->quote("Tim") . ")");

# Same thing, but using placeholders
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?, ?)", undef, 2, "Jochen");
```